# Daisy chain two dell monitors to thinkpad e560 (via onelink pro dock)

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad, docking-station, daisychaining

I own a [ThinkPad E560](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_E560?M=20EV000Txx) 20EV laptop.

I use the laptop with the lid closed, and connected to two external monitors, one [DELL u2415](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/f3cb58)  through HDMI, and an older one through the VGA port.

I would like to buy **a second DELL u2415 monitor** and the [onelink pro dock](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd029981) (*) and connect both dell monitors via DP and daisy-chain.

So the overall setup will be:

**Laptop -> OneLink pro dock -> DP connection to first U2415 monitor -> daisy chain (DP) to second U2415 .**

**Would the above scenario be possible?**

The monitors spec regarding connectivity is the following: [dell u2415 connectivity spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3qlE.png)

Laptop uses an onboard GPU - Intel HD Graphics 520. [It seems that the chipset does support daisy chaining](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P00004CcM9n/for-the-intel-hd-graphics-520-am-i-able-to-hook-up-two-monitors-to-it-and-use-them-as-an-extended-display-this-would-be-two-seperate-monitors-not-the-laptop-monitor-that-is-attached-to-the-laptop?language=en_US). However, **the laptop only has HDMI and VGA outputs**.

I have searched quite a bit but I can't find definitive information, and I would like to be sure before proceeding with the purchases of both the dock and the second monitor.

Looking forward to your help,

(*) - I am not 100% sure if the dock is compatible.  Some lenovo pages list it as compatible, some others don't mention it on the docks supported laptops.  I just can't understand why lenovo doesn't have a fully updated, complete list of laptops supported by each dock - finding different lists and contradicting messages by staff members in the official lenovo forums really doesn't help.  But anyway, based on my research and looking at the spec, it must be compatible..

Comment: Very good question. Since Lenovo made both the dock and the PC, may I suggest asking the nice folks in Lenovo Sales Support https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/contactus if they will confirm this will work? They will provide an authoritative answer you can trust. I'd do it, but they will want the S/N of the PC which I do not have. You need not specify the monitors are Dell, just say you've been promised a pair of DisplayPort monitors to use if it will work.

Comment: thanks buddy. I posted a message on their forums, it seems the only way to contact them. I hope someone replies :)